# Kafka connector stops silently when there is no incoming data for few hours

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a Kafka connector which pulls data from a MySQL view. It appears the connector process stops silently with no error in the logs when there is no new data after a few hours.

A workaround: I added a cron job which restarts the connector every 1 hour. This appeared to make the connector alive for a long time (more than a day) but for some unknown reason, there would be a spike in read throughput on the server even though there was no new data to read and the server became unresponsive.

I also noticed the DB process is in an idle state for the DB query used by the connector.

Are the any configurations I am missing?

Thank you.